# How to make node.js work without node_modules when bundled with webpack?

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, yarnpkg

I want to deploy an app without having to bundle all the node_modules in the folder.

So instead of having this folder deployed:

- app.js
- node_modules (big folder)

To have something like:

- app.js
- binary_dependencies

In the `binary_dependencies` should only include the binaries that can't be included in the `app.js` file.

The reason is because `yarn install` will create a big layer (500MB) in docker and is slow to upload. I wanted to reduce that size.

Comment: you can ignore `node_modules` and run `npm install` on server to download those dependencies.

Comment: So how does the bundled js file get access to the binary node_modules that are not in the bundled js file?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I did not have any "binary_dependencies" - all provided modules were bundled in "app.js". However, at first I had to disable [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) as it purposely excluded some of the modules from my bundled "app.js". After disabling the module, I had to have only "Node" and app.js" on my docker container. By running "node app.js" I was able to start my "express.js" server without having to provide "node_modules" as they were already bundled inside my "app.js".

Answer (score 0):

upload the code with the file package.json, then cd to folder and run npm install
Pay attention to the version you are installing suppose you have the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3"
  }
```

change it to:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "1.18.3"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution still has node_modules folder. I was asking how to bundle the node_modules in the bundles output file from webpack instead and only keep binary modules that can't be bundled in js code separate.